# VB.NET Find a Pixel Color of an Image

Tags: vb.net

How Can I find the HEX color of a specific image pixel?  I've Tried This:

```
 Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("c:\image.jpg")
    PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    Dim b As Bitmap = Me.PictureBox1.Image 
    Dim ver As String = b.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y).ToString 
    Dim veri As String = Hex(b.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y).ToArgb) 
    End Sub
```

This doesn't work as expected:

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseMove
               PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.MyImage
               PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
               Dim b As Bitmap = Me.PictureBox1.Image 'b is not streched..?
               Dim ver As String = b.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y).ToString 
               Dim veri As String = Hex(b.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y).ToArgb) 
        End Sub
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Explain exactly what you expect to happen and exactly what does happen.

Comment: By the way, your code is very bad in both cases from the point of view that you keep on creating new `Image` objects from the same source every time the mouse moves. Why can't you just create the `Image` once, load it into the `PictureBox` once and set the `SizeMode` once?

Comment: With regards to your problem, the `SizeMode` of the `PictureBox` has no effect on the actual `Image` object displayed in the `PictureBox`.  It simply changes how that `Image` is displayed in the control.  Setting that `SizeMode` property is like setting the `Font` property of a `Label`.  It changes what the user sees in the control but has no effect on the underlying data.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post this as an answer because I want to post some code.  You seem to be under the impression that setting the `SizeMode` of a `PictureBox` does/should affect the `Image` it contains.  It doesn't and it shouldn't.  That property is for the UI only, i.e. it affects what the user sees but has no effect on the data.  To prove that to yourself, try creating a WinForms app with two `PictureBoxes` and two `Buttons` and add this code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("image file path here")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal Then
        PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage
    Else
        PictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Normal
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    PictureBox2.Image = PictureBox1.Image

    MessageBox.Show(PictureBox2.Image.Size.ToString())
End Sub
```

You can set the image path to any file you want.

If you click `Button2` you'll see the same image appear in `PictureBox2` as in `PictureBox1` and the dimensions will be displayed.  If you click `Button1` you'll see the image in `PictureBox1` change dimensions to fit the control.  If you click `Button2` again, what you see in `PictureBox2` won't change and neither will the dimensions displayed, because the `Image` object hasn't changed.

If you want to get the colour of the pixel under the mouse cursor then you'd need to call `DrawToBitmap` on the control itself to get a `Bitmap` of what's actually displayed on the screen.